# Issues when fetching data/Json/file from assets manager on Android 10

Tags: android

Below is my code for reading Json file from assets, It works on every other device except  Pixel 3 XL which android version is 10.This device returning null from assets

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader( newInputStreamReader( MyApp.getAppInstance().getAssets().open(fileName)));
        // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
        String mLine;
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(mLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      //log the exception
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Where is the code? @sufiya vs

Comment: what is your target minsdk and target sdk

Comment: minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have given the required permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and for Android 10 issue try using

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

inside your application tag

Comment: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" - Is this needed to get a file inside app folder like assets?